# Static Class Function Overrides Normal Sequence

Tags: c++

I am making two classes: one named `Godfather` and another named `Player`. `Player` has a data member called `madeMan` and `Player`'s default constructor, which I use in the code below, has `madeMan` made (see what I did there) false by default.

My code:

```
class Player;


class Godfather
{
    std::string family;
public:
            Godfather(): family("Corleone") {}
            
            static std::string makeMan(Player & player);
};

class Player
{
    friend std::string Godfather::makeMan(Player & player);
private:
    std::string name;
    bool madeMan;
    std::string familyRank;
public:
     Player(const std::string & aName, const std::string & aFamilyRank, bool madeMan);
     Player(): Player("Aldo", "Associate", false) {}
   
     bool isMade() const {return this->madeMan;}
};


inline Player::Player(const std::string & aName, const std::string & aFamilyRank, bool madeMan):
name(aName), familyRank(aFamilyRank)
{
     std::cout << "Player " << name << " (" << familyRank << ") has been created." << '\n';
}


inline std::string Godfather::makeMan(Player & player)
{
    player.madeMan = true;
    return "Congratulations, " + player.name + ". You're now made.\n";
}

int main()
{
    Player aldo; // uses default constructor, implying that madeMan is false
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << aldo.isMade() << '\n'; // should return false but returns true
    Godfather::makeMan(aldo); // Should convert aldo's madeMan member to true. 
                              // Notice that makeMan follows isMade()
}
```

My problem is explained in the comments in the last three lines of code. Help?

Comment: In the `Player` ctor, you ignore the `madeMan` parameter.

Comment: Your constructor doesnt actually initialize madeMan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the boolean:

```cpp
inline Player::Player(const std::string& aName, const std::string& aFamilyRank, bool madeMan) :
    name(aName), familyRank(aFamilyRank), madeMan(madeMan)
{
    std::cout << "Player " << name << " (" << familyRank << ") has been created." << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Oh... Nevertheless, ```mademan``` is not initialized, which means that accessing its value and therefore the value I got is undefined behavior?

Comment: What do you mean it's not uninitialized? You didn't initialize it. Do you mean the compiler didn't _warn_ you it's uninitialized? The compiler isn't required to - although it's worth turning on all warnings.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker when you are creating objects, you may want to look into some Design Patterns. For example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363338/Factory-Pattern-in-Cplusplus

Comment: Because member variables are constructed in declaration order, the member-initializer-list should construct them in that order (to avoid confusion and potential problems): `name(aName), madeMan(madeMan), familyRank(aFamilyRank)`.